# Is there any micro-controller with ADC > 20 MSPS?

Tags: microcontroller, adc

Is there any micro-controller with ADC more than 20msps (at least 20msps ) ??

Maximum limit I have found is 12.5msps in texsas instruments C2000 f28335

http://www.ti.com/tool/tmdsdock28335#descriptionArea
http://www.ti.com/product/tms320f28335

If not , is there any method to mix more than one channel (ADC) to get higher sampling rate ?

Answer (score 10):

As said by pjc50, typical maximum is around 1 MSPS. But there is some MCU that goes a little higher :

- STM32F302 series : 2 ADC with max 5.14 MSPS @ 12 bits (each) / 9 MSPS @ 6 bits. And it seems to have an interleave mode between the two ADC to have higher MSPS.
  http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/mmc/FM141/FM141/SC1169/SS1576/LN1824/PF253739
- NXP LPC4370 goes up to 80 MSPS @ 12 bits : http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers/cortex_m4/LPC4370FET100.html

It seems that NXP had some high speed ADC so check out NXP site to find others MCU. Also check the datasheets, I'm more digital than analog EE.

Comment: Nice find on the NXP part!

Comment: For a board with the LPC4370 check out the LPC-Link 2.

Answer (score 5):

Edit: these are rare but other answers have found them. I'm leaving the paragraphs that describe potential reasons to choose the two-chip solution other than availability.

At 20MSPS the analog board design becomes more of an issue than usual. You don't want transient noise leaking from the processor into the signal you're sampling via the power and ground rails. It's advantageous to have them in separate packages.

You need a substantial high-speed processor to handle the data and more external RAM to put the results in. So the usual solution here is a high-speed DSP chip with an external ADC.

Comment: In many applications, one may wish to sample some quantity of data, and then ignore huge reams of data while one processes what one has acquired.  Speed of processing isn't necessarily a problem, but in many cases the quantities of data will be greater than a typical micro can hold on-chip.  If one needs to store data to an external memory bus, it may be desirable to have the acquisition circuitry sit directly on the bus so that data doesn't have to flow through the microcontroller before ending up in RAM.

Answer (score 2):

The new [PIC32MZ family](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/press-release/microchips-pic32mz-32-bit-mcus.html) of microcontrollers has a **28 Msps** ADC.