# What is the ARM 32 bit MCU with the fastest ADC?

Tags: adc, arm

I have been trying to find and answer, but it is remarkably tedious and difficult trawling through manufacturers data sheets. The best so far is 12 bit at 2MSPS

Comment: While maybe not technically a duplicate the fastest processor posted here so far happens to be an ARM: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/92787/is-there-any-micro-controller-with-adc-20-msps

Answer (score 2):

As said in this recent question : [Is there any micro-controller with ADC > 20 MSPS?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/92787/is-there-any-micro-controller-with-adc-20-msps/)

- NXP LPC4370 goes up to 80 MSPS @ 12 bits : http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers/cortex_m4/LPC4370FET100.html

Check out NXP site to find other LPC references with high speed ADC (but 80 MSPS seems to be the highest).